# Looking for source for quote from Christian author

Tags: predestination, free-will, cs-lewis

Some years ago I read in a book about Christianity an attempt to explain the apparent paradox between predestination and free will.

I have forgotten the name of the book and its author (it could be C.S. Lewis, but I am far from certain).

The explanation (if that is the correct word) went something like this:

> Events that happened yesterday cannot be changed. The actions we took then cannot be altered. Nevertheless, the choices we made then were made out of our own free will.
>
> We see no conflict between unalterable actions and free will when we look into the past. Why, then, should there be a conflict when we look into the future? God, presumably, is outside time.

This is by no means a verbatim quote. No doubt, it has changed in my mind over the years.

Can anybody tell me where I may have read that explanation?

Comment: **Mod notice:** _<some unrelated comments and answers  removed>_ Please don't use the comment section (or answers) to discuss or debate the theological positions involved here. Stick to the question: what is the source of this quote? Answers should deal with that and comments should ask for or suggest clarification or improvement to the question. Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: Good question. When someone provides an acceptable answer, I encourage you to post here again, should the source you've finally found trigger another question in your mind or a need for clarification. Don

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quote is from C.S.Lewis in "*Mere christianity*", book 4, chapter 3 "Time And Beyond Time".

Comment: This particular question isn't asking for anything other than a precise source for the quotation. Can you confirm that it is in fact by CS Lewis? Otherwise this doesn't answer this question.